# How to fetch an element from arraylist and set it as the class(HTML tag) name?

Tags: java, html, jsp, arraylist

I've an arraylist imported in a jsp page. Now I want to fetch the elements of the arraylist and set it as the html tag class.

```
<div class="<arraylist_item>">
    <select name="doctype" class="my_dropdown" style="color:white; background:#655D78">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Doc Type</option>

        </select>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any kind of help is appreaciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an item from specific array list element use JSP expression language e.g. `<div class="${array.get(specific_index).toString()}"/>`

If you need to iterate over array list and create  element for each element of the list, you can use **forEach** tag from JSTL.
e.g.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${array}">
    <div class="${item.toString()}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

[JSTL tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html)

Comment: I can go with the forEach tag but then what if I want to use that same class name to call a jQuery function? How should I do that?

Comment: you can use a [JSP expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html) for that e.g. `$('#button').addClass('<%= item.toString()%>');`